# How to upload bulk in-apps in apple in xcode 9 as there is no in-app upload option in application loader?

Tags: ios, xcode, tvos, application-loader

After updating to xcode 9, the option to upload in-apps via application loader is removed. Is there any other way to upload in-apps in **bulk**?